# ¿Cómo puedo redireccionar con react-router y el hook useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, redirección, hook, useeffect

Como bien dice la pregunta, quiero que al renderizarse un componente se verifique el valor de una variable, y depende de ello redireccionar a un sitio u otro. Lo que tengo es:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

const Home = ({ loggedIn }) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(loggedIn);
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className='row'>
      <div className='col-12'>
        <p>Home</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  loggedIn: state.auth.isLoggedIn
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Home)
```

Cuando yo entro al sitio recibo correctamente el valor de la variable `loggedIn` en consola. Ahora, quisiera ejecutar algo así:

```
    useEffect(() => {
      loginRedirect();
    },[])

    const loginRedirect = () =>{
     return loggedIn ? <Redirect to='/profile' /> : <Redirect to='/registrar' />
    }
```

Es decir, verificar la variable y redireccionar a `profile` o a `registrar`. Pero recibo el error:

> React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'loginRedirect'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

Supongo que estoy cerca de la solución pero estoy implementando algo mal.

Agradezco cualquier sugerencia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para usar el **Componente** `Redirect`, necesitas incluirlo en el `return` de tu componente, usarlo dentro del `useEffect` no tendrá el resultado que esperas (no va a *renderizar* nada). Recuerda [el principio del *hook*](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html):

> El Hook de efecto te permite llevar a cabo efectos secundarios en componentes funcionales

Por lo tanto, úsalo cuando quieras preparar datos para mostrar (como ejemplo, llamar datos de una api), o bien para acciones "estéticas" (como cambiar el título de la pestaña, manejar estados de "Cargando", etc.).

En tu caso puedes hacerlo de varias maneras, pero sinceramente yo no usaría *useEffect* para ello; se puede hacer simplemente de la siguiente manera:

```
const Home = ({ loggedIn }) => {
  return loggedIn ? <Redirect to='/profile' /> : <Redirect to='/registrar' />;
};
```